# UIWebView Loads in simulator but not in device

Tags: ios, uiwebview

My `UIWebView` is working perfectly in simulator, but not on all my test devices, the `UIWebView` remains blank. Any suggestions to edit this code?

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [worship loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.website.com/current.pdf"] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:60.0]];
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0/2.0) target:self selector:@selector(tick) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try moving your code into:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   //Here
}
```

Your webview is probably = nil in

```
-(void)awakeFromNib {
}
```

Edit: You can also add `NSLog(@"%@", self.webview);` into both `awakeFromNib`, and `viewDidLoad` if you want to see if your web view is nil or not.

Answer (score 0):

During `-awakeFromNib`, your UIWebview will not be initialized yet.  Move your UIWebView code to `-viewDidLoad` (if you only want it to (re)load once) or `-viewDidAppear:` (if you want it to reload every time the view becomes active.

Comment: Those are not making a difference.  Still shows in simulator, not on device.

Comment: What do you do in your tick method?